# Node.js api returning incorrect boolean

Tags: node.js, api, boolean

I have a simple API that returns project information where one of the attributes if a boolean. My server side is returning a `false` boolean but for some reason when it prints out on my client side, it is `true`:

```
api.get('/api/project/:id', function(req, res) {

    knex('projects').where({
            project_code: req.params.id
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data[0].restricted_access) //prints out FALSE
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error: ' + error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
});
```

My API call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/project/" + project_code,
    success: function(data, status) {

        console.log(data[0].restricted_access) //prints out TRUE

    },
    error: function(a, b,c ) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
});
```

Sample project object:

```
[ { id: 14,
    project_code: 'abc123',
    restricted_access: false 
} ]
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: does it also magically change when you just do `res.send({restricted_access: false})` ?

Comment: nah, that actually returns false...

Comment: how about when you do `console.log(data[0].toJSON())`. IF you overrided the serialize method, that could be the cause

Answer (score 0):

We just need to find out at which point it breaks:

```
console.log(data[0].restricted_access)
```

This return false so your bookshelf object is good. Lets test whether an http interceptor of any sort on the front-end is the problem:

```
res.send({restricted_access: false})
```

If your front-end retrieved false properly, then this change happened while serializing your bookshelf object.

As a final resort, lets try:

```
console.log(data[0].toJSON())
```

Investigate whether it's false or true. If it is true, then search through your code to find out where you overwrote the serialize method :)

If that didn't solve your problem either, then I can only wish good luck to you